# Dual boot manager showing the wrong disk

Tags: dual-boot, bios

I have a dual boot system with two separate disks, one for Windows (on a Samsung SSD), and one for Ubuntu (on a WD HDD). Today, Ubuntu booted into BusyBox shell with `(initramfs)`. Then I noticed that from my BIOS boot up menu, the boot manager showed the same disk for both Windows and Ubuntu.
Something like this:

```
Windows Boot Manager (M.2_2: Samsung SSD .....)(500GB)
ubuntu (M.2_2: Samsung SSD ....)(500GB)
```

Normally, the ubuntu shows WD HDD but now it's showing the SSD for Windows. How did this happen and how to fix it?

### Update

The ubuntu disk is `sdb`.  `fdisk -l` returned:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 149.5 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD1600AAJS-0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000281dc

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb2       1052670 312580095 311527426 148.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1052672 312580095 311527424 148.6G 83 Linux
```

Mounting the partition had the following errors:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb5 /mnt
mount: /mnt: cannot mount; probably corrupted filesystem on /dev/sdb5.
```

This is what Disks showed:
[Disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myZwz.png)

This is what GParted showed:[GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tOT4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually happens when root partition was not shutdown clean.
do you now whrre it is you root partition?
from initramfs you can fsck the root partition and then boot again.

try.. 
`#ls -l /dev/disk/by-partlabel` 
->to figure out which partition need to be checked.

then try.. 
 (asuming your wd hdd is sda and ubuntu is installed on partition 1)
`#fsck /dev/sda1`
-> to check and fix the partition.

Another option (with gui) is to boot from a ubuntu pendrive and use disks to check and fix the partition.

Comment: I tried fsck /dev/sdb2 but it did nothing. It only returned its version.

Comment: Seems to be sdb5 the one need to be checked.